# Trying to get info from two tables with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

My page info and images are stored in two separate tables.  I want 'type' and 'body' from the table "page".  Then 'images' from the table "page_images".  Both obviously from the same page.
I want a few teasers of random pages.  But, I need ONE image (even though many are stored for each page) from "page_images" and the 'type' and 'body' from "page". (images are stored as 'image_loc' in the table page_images)

```
-- TABLE  page

page_id | user_id | url_title     | title         | type | full_location | phone | body
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1       | jazz_showcase | Jazz Showcase | Jazz | ...           | ...   | ... 

-- TABLE  page_images

image_id | user_id | page_title     | image_loc
-----------------------------------------------
1        | 1       | jazz_showcase  | ...
2        | 3       | jazz_showcase  | ...
3        | 2       | something_else | ...
```

This query doesn't work...

```
function OnTheSpot() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT page.body AS desc, page.style AS styles, page_images.image_loc AS images
                                FROM page
                                LEFT JOIN page_images
                                ON page.url_title = page_images.page_title 
                                ORDER BY RAND()
                                LIMIT 1
                            ");
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $desc = $fetch['desc'];
            $styles = $fetch['styles'];
            $images = $fetch['images'];
            echo $desc.'<br />';
            echo $styles.'<br />';
            echo $images.'<br />';
            }
        }
```

I would want 5 or so random pages demoed.  Each page with a limit of one image and the type and body displayed.  How would this be query'd.

Comment: Every time you use `ORDER BY RAND()`, a puppy dies :(

Comment: Explanation of why `ORDER BY RAND()` is bad: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: Please respond to the question.  Good article though.

Comment: Have you tried `ON page_images.page_title = page.url_title` instead? For some reason my (rather tired) brain is telling me that the ordering of that part is important, though I can't come up with a reason why.

Comment: No that didn't do it.  I keep getting the 'mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...' error.  So, it's something in the query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `desc` to e.g. `descr`. `Desc` is a reserved word in MySQL and you can't use it.

See: [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

**EDIT:** Here is also a query for you, which probably solves your problem:

```
$query = "SELECT page.body AS descr, page.url_title, page.style AS styles, page_images.image_loc AS images FROM page,page_images WHERE page_images.page_title = page.url_title ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Dude, nice.  That worked perfectly.  Is there a way to show more than one image for a single page.  If I change LIMIT 5.  It shows 5 pages with one image for each.  How could I Show multiple images for one page?  Thanks again

Comment: You could use desc, but it would have to be enclosed in backticks at all times.

Comment: @Graham I'm not sure. You could do it with two different queries, first get the page and then get five images for that page. I'm quite sure there exists a lot more sophisticated way to do it but for now that might get you going.